# RocksDB exception in Kafka Streams with kafka_2.13-3.2.0 running on Window

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have **kafka 2.13-3.2.0 running on Window machine**. I am trying stream Join operation and getting following error. I can see same issue fixed in 1.0.1 version as per  : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6162

But I am still getting this error with kafka 2.13-3.2.0.

Error Logs:

```
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Failed to create dir: D:\tmp\kafka-streams\join_driver_application\1_0\KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000014-store\KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000014-store:1661385600000: Invalid argument
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:197)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Does `D:\tmp` already exist?

Comment: yes, D:\tmp  is present

Comment: Hmm. Not particular sure. All I really know is that Kafka is not well tested on windows. Also, Windows has a limit on the number of characters in folder paths, and  the error seems to say there is a colon in the file name, which simply isn't allowed... Maybe there is a RockDB configuration to override this